# JS concatenate numbers with operator sign

Tags: javascript

Maybe tittle is not too descriptive, but how do I get this kind of result

```js
var string = 11+'-'+10
// expected result 11-10

console.log(string);
```

Every time I try to do the above I get 1, or whatever the result of the subtraction is

I will be a little bit clear about this. What I want to do with this is generate a button with onclick like this:

```
onClick = method(1,[11-10, 12-10])

method(id,...array){
 console.log(array)
 //result [1,2]
}
```

even if inspecting the button actually shows the correct output

Comment: Your question outputs `11-10`, so it's unclear what you're doing to get an output of `1`

Comment: The code you provided produces exactly what you say your expected result is.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include an example that actually demonstrates your issue?

Comment: Assuming you have a different scenario than what you presented to us... use `toString()` to ensure the numbers are interpreted as strings. E.g. `(11).toString() + '-' + (10).toString()`.

Comment: Use JavaScript template literals: let string = `11-10` the 11-10 is should be enclosed in backticks not single-quotation or double-quotation

Comment: @NoraSöderlund how does it make it better?

Comment: @Konrad the question has since my comment been updated. Regardless, like I said, "to ensure the numbers are interpreted as strings" - use `toString()`. `(11).toString() + - + (10).toString()` > `'11-10'` vs `11 + - + 10` > `1`. But this no longer really applies to the question, since it's been clarified.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you use

```
11+'-'+10
```

In the second one, you use

```
11-10
```

There is a clear difference

Using the first method in the second code will work as expected

```
method(1,[11+'-'+10, 12+'-'+10])
```

To make it shorter just use strings

```
method(1,['11-10', '12-10'])
```